# Can not authenticate Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

The application should be transferred to another page after authentication. But for some reason wrote in the logs that all Ok authentication passed.But the transition to another page does not happen. What could be the problem?

**auth.guard.ts:**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Angular2TokenService} from "angular2-token";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authTokenService:Angular2TokenService,
              private router:Router){}

  canActivate() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page
    this.router.navigate(['/sign_in']);
    return false;
}

}
```

**auth.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Angular2TokenService} from "angular2-token";
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Response} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  userSignedIn$:Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  constructor(private authService:Angular2TokenService) {
    this.userSignedIn$.next(this.authService.userSignedIn());
  }

  logOutUser():Observable<Response>{

    return this.authService.signOut().map(
        res => {
          this.userSignedIn$.next(false);
          return res;
        }
    );
  }

  logInUser(signInData: {email:string, password:string}):Observable<Response>{

    return this.authService.signIn(signInData).map(
        res => {
          this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
          return res
        }
    );

  }

   registerUser(signUpData:  {email:string, password:string, passwordConfirmation:string}):Observable<Response>{
    return this.authService.registerAccount(signUpData).map(
        res => {
          this.userSignedIn$.next(true);
          return res
        }
    );
  }

}
```

**sign-in.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

  signInUser = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
  };

  @Output() onFormResult = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private _router: Router, private authService:AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSignInSubmit(){

    this.authService.logInUser(this.signInUser).subscribe(

        res => {
          if(res.status == 200){
            // loginForm.resetForm();
            this.onFormResult.emit({signedIn: true, res});
            this._router.navigate(['user_profile']);
          }
        },

        err => {
          console.log('err:', err);
          // loginForm.resetForm();
          this.onFormResult.emit({signedIn: false, err});
        }
    )

  }




}
```

**sign-in.component.html:**

```
<div class="main-content">
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSignInSubmit()" #f="ngForm" >


                <div class="row">

                  <div >
                    <input id="email"
                           type="email"
                           required
                           name='email' 
                           [(ngModel)]="signInUser.email" 
                           class="validate">

                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                  </div>


                  <div >
                    <input id="password" 
                           type="password" 
                           required  
                           name='password' 
                           [(ngModel)]="signInUser.password" 
                           class="validate">

                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                  </div>

                  <div >
                    <button type="submit" 
                    > 
                      Login </button>
                  </div>


                </div>

              </form>

</div>
```

Comment: after login, can you check `localStorage.getItem('currentUser')` in browser console? does it have any value or not?

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong path in user_profile try the following,

```
 this._router.navigate(['/user_profile']);
```

Comment: it did not help me

Comment: so where is the issue? can you produce a stackblitz demo

Answer (score 0):

If your auth guard is on your 'user_profile' path; then you need to set 'currentUser' in your localStorage. Otherwise your guard will just redirect to back to the signin page.